# Prove this identity$ \cos u \cos v \cos t = \,\frac14[\cos(t-u+v)+\cos(t+u-v)+\cos(t-u-v)+\cos(t+u+v)];$

Tags: trigonometry

The problem reads as follows.

Prove the identity

$$ \cos u \cos v \cos t = $$
$$ \frac14[\cos(t-u+v)+\cos(t+u-v)+\cos(t-u-v)+\cos(t+u+v)]$$

Hint: begin with the right side and use cosine sum identity for three angles.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you please explain why you are stuck and why the hint didn't help?

Comment: The hint is a good one ... but it *really* helps if you have an additional $\cos(t-u+v)$ term (because otherwise this isn't an identity). :)  By the way: Once you have four terms, the ["prosthaphaeresis" (sum-to-product) formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) are probably easier to apply than the triple-angle-sum formulas.

Comment: The hint helped and gave me direction. but I didn't know to add an additional term like Goos said.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve such problems with complex numbers:
$$
\cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}
$$
If you set $a = e^{it}, b = e^{iu}, c = e^{iv}$, just observe
\begin{align*}
(a + a^{-1})(b + b^{-1})(c + c^{-1})
&= \left[ abc + a^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1} \right] \\
&+ \left[ abc^{-1} + a^{-1}b^{-1}c \right] \\
&+ \left[ ab^{-1}c^{-1} + a^{-1}bc \right] \\
&+ \left[ ab^{-1}c + a^{-1}bc^{-1} \right] \\
\end{align*}

As Blue notes in the comments, you will need an additional term, $\cos(t - u + v)$.  Now you just have to divide the above by $8$ on both sides, and match each of the four terms above with one of the four terms $\cos(t + u + v)$, $\cos(t + u - v)$, $\cos(t - u + v)$, $\cos(t - u - v)$.

Answer (score 0):

> $$\cos u \cos v = \frac12 (\cos(u+v) + \cos(u-v))$$

proof:
$$
\cos u \cos v = \Re (e^{iu}\cos v) = \frac 12\Re (e^{iu}(e^{iv}+ e^{-iv}))
\\
= \frac 12\Re (e^{i(u+v)}+ e^{i(u-v)}) 
\\
= \frac12 (\cos(u+v) + \cos(u-v))
$$

> $$\cos u \cos v \cos t = \frac14 (\cos(u+v+t) +\cos(u+v-t) + \cos(u-v+t) + \cos(u-v-t))
> $$

proof:
$$
\cos u \cos v \cos t = \frac12 (\cos(u+v)\cos t + \cos(u-v)\cos t)
\\
= \frac14 (\cos(u+v+t) +\cos(u+v-t) + \cos(u-v+t) + \cos(u-v-t))
$$
when you apply twice the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first recall that for every 
$$
\cos p\cos q=\frac12[\cos(p-q)+\cos(p+q)]\quad \forall p,q \in \mathbb{R}
$$ 
Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
\cos t\cdot\cos u\cdot\cos v&=&\frac12\cos t\cdot[\cos(u-v)+\cos(u+v)]\\
&=&\frac12\cos t\cdot\cos(u-v)+\frac12\cos t\cdot\cos(u+v)\\
&=&\frac14[\cos(t-u+v)+\cos(t+u-v)+\cos(t-u-v)+\cos(t+u+v)].
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Setting

$$ u=v=t=0,$$
we get

$$ 1=\frac34 $$

So added the obvious missing term in the title so  that

$$ \cos t\cdot\cos u\cdot\cos v= $$

$$ \frac14[\cos(t-u+v)+\cos(t+u-v)+\cos(t-u-v)+\cos(t+u+v)].$$

Simplification can be as follows

$$ \cos (t+ u+v)= c_{t+u} c_v-s_{t+u}s_v$$

$$ = + c_tc_uc_v-s_ts_uc_v-s_vs_tc_u-s_us_vc_t$$

$$\cos(t+u-v) = +...-...+...+...$$

$$\cos(u+v-t) = +...+...+...-...$$

$$\cos(t+u-v) = +...+...-...+...$$

Adding the four equations only first terms remain, rest cancel out and the  result follows.